# webclient error (random and very very annoying)

Tags: c#, stream, webclient

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(wc_OpenReadCompleted);
wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));


void wc_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{ 
  if (e.Error != null || e.Cancelled)
  {
    //randomly, this code gets hit and 
    //there is no inner exception - just says "an exception occurred during a webclient request"
```

The error described in code happens randomly and if the same webclient request is made after that it works. Or if a new resource request is made the old one which got an error now comes before the new request......

This is very strange, any gurus here have a clue why it might be?

EDIT: information on error

> System.Net.WebException: An exception
>   occurred during a WebClient request.
>   ---> System.Exception ---> System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL
>   has been returned from a call to a COM
>   component.    at
>   System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.InternalEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.<>c_*DisplayClass5.b*_4(Object
>   sendState)    at
>   System.Net.AsyncHelper.<>c_*DisplayClass2.b*_0(Object sendState)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.Net.AsyncHelper.BeginOnUI(SendOrPostCallback
>   beginMethod, Object state)    at
>   System.Net.BrowserHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request, IAsyncResult result)    at
>   System.Net.WebClient.OpenReadAsyncCallback(IAsyncResult
>   result)    --- End of inner exception
>   stack trace ---

The URL is a simple string having count of no more than 200.

Comment: What's the type of the exception? Have you tried looking at what's happening at the network level using Wireshark?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: exception = "an exception occurred during a webclient request" and that is all I get back. I haven't used Wireshark but installing it right away now. Using fiddler however I don't even see the HTTP request made when I get this error; However, when I make another WebClient request - the one where I got the error shows up in fiddler (request type = GET, HTTP/1.1) and the new request I made also comes after this.... so it is very strange.

Comment: (just to add to my comment): After receiving the error and not seeing the fiddler session for it - If I make another call and now see two requests being made in fiddler, and if I look at the details for the request when I got an error I see that the `ClientBeginRequest` timestamp is at the newer time when I made the second request. So it is almost like the webClient request is stuck somewhere in memory or buffer and on the next request it forces it to execute. Also, I installed WireShark but I haven't been able to recreate this error ever since :) - but I'll update here once I do.

Comment: @VoodooChild: That's the *message* of the exception possibly - but you should be seeing an actual exception... if your logging only contains the message but not the exception type, it's worth fixing that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I posted the actual exception in my question above. I don't know why I thought that the message of the exception would be the same as what's in the exception, thanks for pointing that out. Basically the exception is `Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component` on line `wc.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));` and again there is no request made to the server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @VoodooChild: Ick. That does look nasty...

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Hi, the error was being caused by a third party control in my app, which was blocking the UI thread (silverlight app); the async call to the webclient (which runs on a different thread) was somehow ? (not sure about this part) affected and that's why we were seeing the error in the webclient completed. If I make the same webclient async call using the Dispatcher class which will execute the code on the UI Thread, then this error seems to get resolved and webClient completed is executed without any errors.

Comment: @VoodooChild: That's very odd. I thought the WebClient async call *would* try to use the dispatcher thread... it does on Windows Phone 7. Oh well - glad it's resolved.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Would you like to add some of your comments on questions as an answer so I can award you the bounty?

Comment: @VoodooChild: None of my comments were *that* helpful, as far as I can see. Not worth a bounty :)

Comment: Could you please elaborate your solution, please. It seems I have the same problem, but not able to resolve it so far.

Comment: @tomasK - I don't remember all the details, however it seems to be a threading issue. The UI thread which calls the webClient method might have been blocked and carries out the any requests in its queue on the next usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code would be hit if cancelled or error being generated. I suspect you are hitting a networking issue, so I would fire up [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and watch the HTTP requests and make sure you are getting them back correctly.

Comment: I agree, but the problem I am running in to is that there is no HTTP request made for my `wc.OpenReadAsync(..)` call when I get the error. However when I make another request I see two fiddler sessions for two requests one where I got the error and another one I just made. Any clues?

Comment: (just to add to my comment): After receiving the error and not seeing the fiddler session for it - If I make another call and now see two requests being made in fiddler, and if I look at the details for the request when I got an error I see that the `ClientBeginRequest` timestamp is at the newer time when I made the second request. So it is almost like the webClient request is stuck somewhere in memory or buffer and on the next request it forces it to execute.

Comment: Sounds like network buffering. The Windows network stack and potentially your network card (physically and driver software) all implement buffers. This can cause your network requests to not work exactly as expected. You also want to check for caching issues, I had the same scenario previously (except my client was IE 9) and it was the IE 9 redirect caching that was causing the problem: http://www.sadev.co.za/content/redirected-down-one-way-clearing-internet-explorer-host-redirect-cache I doubt that is your problem because your client is code, but make sure you aren't caching anywhere in code

Answer (score 0):

I am going to hazard a guess that it's timing out. I am also going to further guess that it may be a DNS issue.

It's possible that the DNS is timing out. This would be consistent with you not seeing the request in Fiddler.

I suppose it's not impossible that the request would then be filled later when you try again, and this time the DNS works. Maybe. This point I'm a bit fuzzy on, but whatever.

If you use a URL with an IP address instead of a domain name, do you still have the same problem?

Comment: Not a bad suggestion regarding the timing out; but it seems to have been a threading issue. The UI thread which calls the webClient method might have been blocked and carries out the any requests in its queue on the next usage....

Answer (score 0):

Probably URL is very long. I've same issue on WP8 with 2900 symbols length URL